# Closing Channel Inside of a Struct

Tags: go, websocket, concurrency, goroutine, channel

I've been trying to look through existing posts about closing a channel, but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. I have two channels inside of a struct. After making the channels, I tried to run `defer close(channelName)` immediately after, but the channels immediately closed and I got an error. If I don't deal with closing the channels, the code runs fine, but doesn't shut down gracefully and I have to use ctrl z to suspend the program, since it's still running after using ctrl c. Here are the important parts of the code:

```
type WebsocketClient struct {
    pubSocket  ws_client.Socket
    privSocket ws_client.Socket
    pubChan    chan interface{}
    privChan   chan interface{}
}

type KrakenClient struct {
    WebSocket WebsocketClient
    Testing   bool
}

func (client *KrakenClient) initChannels() {
    client.WebSocket.pubChan = make(chan interface{})
    client.WebSocket.privChan = make(chan interface{})

    //defer close(client.WebSocket.pubChan)
    //defer close(client.WebSocket.privChan)
}

func (client *KrakenClient) InitWebSocketClient(wg *sync.WaitGroup, testing bool) {
    client.initTesting(testing)
    client.initChannels()
    client.startWebSocketConnection(wg)
}

func (client *KrakenClient) PubDecoder(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ctx context.Context) {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()
    defer client.WebSocket.pubSocket.Close()

    if err := PubSocketGuard(client.WebSocket); err != nil { // guard clause checker. makes sure i'm actually using a public WebSocket
        panic(err)
    }

    var res interface{}

    ws_client.ReceiveLocker(&client.WebSocket.pubSocket)
    client.WebSocket.pubSocket.OnTextMessage = func(message string, socket ws_client.Socket) {
        res = ws_client.PubJsonDecoder(message, client.Testing)
        client.WebSocket.pubChan <- res
    }
    ws_client.ReceiveUnlocker(&client.WebSocket.pubSocket)

    <-ctx.Done()
    log.Println("closing public socket")
    return
}

func (client *KrakenClient) PubListen(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ctx context.Context, ohlcMap *types.OHLCVals) {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    for c := range client.WebSocket.pubChan {
        switch v := c.(type) {
        // More code here. Not important to the channel problem
    }
    <-ctx.Done()
}

func main() {
    var testing bool = true

    comms := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(comms, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    kraken := &kraken_client.KrakenClient{}
    kraken.InitWebSocketClient(&wg, testing)
    go kraken.PubDecoder(&wg, ctx)
    kraken.SubscribeToOHLC(&wg, []string{"BTC/USD"}, 5)

    ohlcMap := types.OHLCVals{}

    go kraken.PubListen(&wg, ctx, &ohlcMap)

    <-comms
    cancel()
    wg.Wait()

}
```

In summary, struct `KrakenClient` has a type `WebsocketClient`, which holds 2 WebSockets and 2 channels. Calling the `InitWebSocketClient` func on the `KrakenClient` struct creates the two channels and connects to the WS server. Once connected to the server, I start to unmarshal all responses and send those responses to a channel. I then subscribe to a specific endpoint, and start to "listen" to the responses (actually go through the data and add it to the ohlcMap variable that's passed to the listen func depending on certain circumstances). I just don't understand where I should be closing the channels. Do I need to create a `Close` function on my `KrakenClient` struct that defers when the channels are closed? If so, where would it even go? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You must call defer in main func because when you call defer in initChannels func it's immediately close your channels after making.
The defer always execute when the function (initChannels in your code) has been return.

you can write a closing function for close the channels and call it on main func like as:

```
func (client *KrakenClient) closeChannels() {
    close(client.WebSocket.pubChan)
    close(client.WebSocket.privChan)
}

func (client *KrakenClient) initChannels() {
    client.WebSocket.pubChan = make(chan interface{})
    client.WebSocket.privChan = make(chan interface{})
}

func main() {
    ...
    kraken.InitWebSocketClient(&wg, testing)
    defer kraken.closeChannels()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This doesn't seem to totally take car of doing the job, sadly

Comment: What is it's problem ?

Comment: It continued to keep running even after I would press ctrl+c. I ended up finding a way to make it work

```func (client *KrakenClient) DeferChanClose(g *trading_bot.ConcurrencySettings) {
 g.Wg.Add(1)
 defer g.Wg.Done()
 <-g.Ctx.Done()

 defer close(client.WebSocket.pubChan)
 defer close(client.WebSocket.privChan)
 defer close(client.WebSocket.bookChan)

 defer client.WebSocket.pubSocket.Close()
 defer client.WebSocket.bookSocket.Close()
 defer client.WebSocket.privSocket.Close()

 log.Println("closing channels")
}```

Comment: Not sure why the formatting is so strange, but I hope the main point can be understood